Should I kill off my main character at the end of my story?
I have had an idea for the entirety of my book to kill off my main character, Jack. But I'm currently having second thoughts. I'm almost through writing and I need help ASAP! I feel like it's important to the plot but I'm not sure. For context, He is a 14 year old boy, I'm not sure if that is important or not but I added it just in case.
EDIT: Thank you for the responses, I have decided to kill him off, but have his death be a major (hopefully) shock. He will disappear for a while before his sister Mari finds him. I'm really excited

First off, You are the author, you know your story, you know what's best. I can't give a definite yes or no answer because I don't know the book, plot or character and therefore can't say for sure what would work best. You on the other hand have followed this character and this plot, heck you've written this character and this plot so ultimately, you know what's best for the book and it has to be your decision. Trust yourself! You got this.
But here are some things to consider:
The plot has already been shaped
If you have known from the beginning of the writing process that your character was going to die, this will have leaked into your writing, whether you knew it or not. It will have shaped the plot, the character and any relationships the character has. Therefore, suddenly changing the ending could be risky as something the readers were expecting to happen suddenly doesn't. Unless the alternative ending is done well, it could be a meh or even dissapointing ending.  It would be like watching a film where it starts with someone saying "I'm going to ask her on a date!" They prepare and get mentored, face obstacles and challenges, all in preparation for asking this girl on a date. The end of the film comes, they knock on her door . . . and run away scared before it gets opened. End of film.
Persoanlly, I would have a few moments to yell at the TV if this happened. Obviosuly, it's not completely the same, as in that example, it was stated what the eventual goal was going to be. Killing someone off probably isn't going to be stated outright but there will be hints and clues throughout the novel that readers will pick up on, hints that insinuate what's going to happen. The readers will expect it and when it doesn't happen it's a little disappointing. That being said . . .
What would the alternative ending be?
If done well, a different ending could also work. If it doesn't end with a death, what would an equally satifying and conclusive ending be? Although it isn't impossible to think of an alternative end for your character, it is made harder by the fact that (as stated in the last point) you have written the entire book with his death as the ultimate goal. Would switching to something else make the ending better or would it jarr the reader as they were expecting him to die?
Analyse why you feel unsure.
I have killed off many character before and I've heard a lot of other authors talking about when they did the same. Especially if they are a main character, the author will have deep attachment to them as they have spent time creacting them. Although it's not the same as if a living person were to die, there is an element of grief to killing off a character. That's completely normal! You've created this person from scratch and you don't want to see them die. Is it this feeling that is making you hesitate or is there another reason? 
It's possible you have subconsciously realised it won't work and you simply need to figure out why. Try and understand where your feelings of doubt and unease have come from. If it's purely hesitation out of sadness, just try and go for it (imagine how the readers will feel!). If it is for other reasons, see if there is a way to fix that problem before deciding whether to change the ending.
Are you simply wondering if main character death is a safe route to go down?
It's possible I've written all this when really what you're asking is 'will readers think that killing off Jack is a good ending?' And that's a much harder question to answer.
In my opinion, it is a valid option that not enough authors take. I can think of at least 3 books where the main character died and it has been done incredibly well, leaving me absolutely devastated but content and satisfied with how the book ended. The key point is that it has to be done well. If it's done half-heartedly then it's just a bit annoying. Other things that should be considered to make it a good ending are:

Do we get to see the effect of the mc death on others?
Do we get to see the effect of the mc on the world as a whole?
Why/how was their death meaninful (shown through a change in society/environment around them, usually for the better)?

If these questions aren't answered (in my opinion) the ending feels incomplete. It could be an emotive and beautifully written death but I wont feel like the story has ended because I haven't seen the ending.
 Pov is also important to consider.
Others may completely disagree with me and say they hate it when the author kills of the mc at the end, but if it's just a vote of confidence you need, GO FOR IT! Trust yourself and go for it! You know what's best ;D

My suggestion is to consider whether the death at the end seems a plausible outcome of the story. It could be unsatisfying to the reader if a death seems a surprise rather than a logical end.
For example, the protagonist sacrificing himself for a worthy goal or person, or dying because he is paying a price for something, makes logical sense and can be satisfying.
I suspect if a reader is not just sad but surprised or shocked at the death, that it seems a senseless death, they will be unhappy and unsatisfied.
As an example, the protagonist dies at the end of The Judas Line. I was sad about the death, because I liked the character and hoped to read more. The death was a small surprise initially, but I knew the character was weary and used up and had major sins to atone for. I would say the character "died well." It was a little disappointing but was not a shocking or senseless death.

1 Character growth
A basic principle in storytelling is:

If a character successfully grows and changes, he is rewarded with achieving his goals.
If a character fails to develop, he is punished by failure.

When a character "gets what he deserves" (either reward or punishment), the reader is satisfied.
2 Genre conventions
Some genres, like grimdark, require a bleak ending, others, like romantic love stories, must have a happy ending.
Recommendation
I would never disappoint my readers by slapping an ending in their face they didn't expect and don't want.
